# Print invalid email method in java

Tags: java

This is what I have left to do:

You should have it returning the two emails that do not contain a period and the **@** sign.  The third condition is that the method should check if there is a space

Use a for-loop or enhanced for-loop to look through your student objects
    Get the email string for each student using your getter method
    Use the `contains()` method from the String class
        Check for three conditions 
            Does not `contains(“@“)`
            OR Does not `contains(“.”)`
            OR  `contains (“ “)`
            http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm
                NOTE that the contains method returns a boolean value of true/false.
                For the invalid emails method you can use the exclamation character to check if it does not contain.

I'm trying to just print out the invalid emails. There are mistakes in the emails on purpose.

```
public class Roster{

  private static ArrayList<Student> myRoster = new ArrayList<>();
  public static void main(String[] args){
   Roster.add("1", "John", "Smith", "John1989@gmail.com", 20 , 88, 79, 59);
   add("2", "Suzan", "Erickson", "Erickson_1990@gmailcom", 19, 91, 72, 85);
   add("3", "Jack", "Napoli", "The_lawyer99yahoo.com", 19, 85, 84, 87);
   add("4", "Erin", "Black", "Erin.black@comcast.net", 22, 91, 98, 82);
   add("5", "Marlene","Conliff", "Mseeds1@wgu.edu", 47, 95, 98, 100);


 //This is where I am having problems:
   public static void printInvalidEmail(){
        for(Student b: myRoster){
            if(b.getemail().equals(email)){
                if(b.getemail() = "., @"){
                    System.out.println(studentId + " valid email.");
                    return;
                }else{
                    System.out.println(studentId + " invalid email");
                    return;
```

Comment: So, where is the code that you've written, and that you have problems with? Or are you asking us to write it for you?

Comment: very first problem in this code, you are trying to add elements to the class `Roster` not to the actual list you created (since it is static you can use). So `Roster.add...` -> `myRoster.add...` for all adds...